# Are PCB spreading inductance and loop inductance the same thing?

Tags: capacitor, pcb-design, inductance, decoupling-capacitor, pcb-layers

[image: i]

Hi there, 
there is a mention of power/ground net spreading inductance in the Figure 1. I'm assuming this is the same as PCB spreading inductance. If so, is loop inductance the same thing here? Or does PCB spreading inductance mean just the inductance from the plane/trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just the inductance due to the plane over the distance (2).  So it is part of the loop inductance.

From Intel [AN 574](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/programmable/us/en/pdfs/literature/an/an574.pdf) (they have nearly the same picture):

> The spreading inductance is design dependent and scales as a function
>   of the dielectric thickness (h) between the power/ground plane. It is
>   determined by the spatial location (d) of the capacitor with respect
>   to the load. Minimizing the dielectric thickness (h) reduces the
>   capacitor location sensitivity and allows you to place the capacitors
>   farther away from the load.
>   [image]